# ARM Assembly - Sum of two unsigned 32 bit ints returned in an unsigned 64 bit int

Tags: arm

A + B (both uint32_int). The function will return a value of uint64_int. What do I do?

I've tried doing

```
ADDS R0, R0, R2
ADC R1, R1, R3
BX LR
```

but it gave me some huge number.

Comment: Can you explain which register is `A` and which is `B`? And where you want the result to be stored?

Comment: I did R1 and R0 for A, R2 and R3 for B, and it stored the result in both R1 and R0, but I'm not sure if I did it right. The available registers for use is R0-R15 for this.

Comment: What is the initial value of R0? Your first instruction adds R2 to whatever value is already in R0. Similarly, the second instruction adds R3 to whatever value is already in R1 (plus carry). I think you would be well-served by just stepping through the code in a debugger to see what you are calculating and what ends up in R0 and R1 when you are done.

Comment: Yeah I see what I did wrong initially. It should be like this: A (Uses R0) + B (Uses R1) = SUM (R1:R0)

Comment: yes that is the key, which registers contain the input values?  and which registers will hold the output values, and then the last step is what if anything goes into the upper 32 bits from the result of the add of the lower 32 bits?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about your title question then you add the two 32 bit numbers and the only other thing you need in the upper 32 bits is the carry out, so you use adc with zeros (for unsigned).

```
unsigned long long fun0 ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(a+b);
}

unsigned long long fun1 ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(a+((unsigned long long)b));
}


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e1a03001    mov r3, r1
   4:   e3a01000    mov r1, #0
   8:   e0800003    add r0, r0, r3
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000010 <fun1>:
  10:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
  14:   e0910000    adds    r0, r1, r0
  18:   e2a31000    adc r1, r3, #0
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

so fun1 clearly, not fun0.  I wonder why the extra instruction in fun0.

Comment: Not sure which instruction you are calling the "extra" instruction. The `mov r1, #0` is to promote the 32-bit unsigned to a 64-bit unsigned. The `mov r3, r1` is to save the value of `r1` (for the upcoming add) before we clobber it. Could have saved an instruction by reordering as `add r0, r0, r1 / mov r1, #0 / bx lr` to avoid the clobber hazard.